# Passing Messages Between Fibers Quasar

Tags: java, fiber, quasar

I am using a quasar fiber to listen to and process messages on a `QueueObjectChannel`. I am not sure what Object I am supposed to use as the message queue between fibers. The problem I am having is I don't understand what is supposed to be passed into the `QueueObjectChannel` Constructor. According to the javadoc the constructor is supposed to take `QueueObjectChannel(co.paralleluniverse.strands.queues.BasicQueue<Message> queue, Channels.OverflowPolicy policy, boolean singleProducer, boolean singleConsumer)` but that seems counterintuitive because I am trying to build something that implements `BasicQueue`.

Am I supposed to implement the interface?

Is my understanding of inter fiber communication completely off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually one wants to (and should) use the channels API, not the backing queues. For example different queue implementations can only work and/or are only optimal with some data types, with threads and/or fibers, with a specific buffer configuration, when there's a single consumer etc.

As [explained here](http://docs.paralleluniverse.co/quasar/#channels) just use the static [`Channels.new*Channel` methods](http://docs.paralleluniverse.co/quasar/javadoc/co/paralleluniverse/strands/channels/Channels.html) passing in the properties you need and you'll get a channel backed by a queue that is tailor-suited to your use case.